# Holocaust Remembrance Fast Day

Tags: fast-days, holocaust-shoah

Rabbi Yom Tov Schwarz (See: “*EYES TO SEE: Recovering Ethical Torah Principles Lost in the Holocaust*”) argues that the Jewish people (led by the Torah observant community) should designate a fast day in remembrance and mourning of the Holocaust and it should be on a day that doesn’t already have a fast associated with other events (e.g., 9th of Av, 10th of Tevet, etc).  Have any other Gedolim agreed with this and do any Torah observant communities fast on a day solely in remembrance and mourning of the Holocaust?

Comment: Perhaps we should, but I think that the Gedolim nowadays don't consider themselves great enough to make takanos like that.

Comment: Many gedolim have said that it is specifically Tisha B'av that is the appropriate day. That is why we have kinos, such as that written by Rav Schwab or the Novominsker, to be said as part of the kinos of Tisha B'av.

Comment: No. The Gedoley Torah did not agree to that proposal because we do not have the power to establish fast days anymore

Comment: @Schmerel that's not true

Answer (score 2):

In his kiruv 20+ CD series, Rabbi Dovid Orlofsky said, "We observe all of the catastrophic tragedies of our nation on one specific day: Tisha B’Av. The loss of our Temple is the root cause of all our suffering in exile." *(If I ever get a hold of Rabbi Orlofsky and obtain permission to publish the manuscript of those incredible shiurim, this response would be in chapter 5 question 8...)*

Although lack of evidence is no proof, Rabbi Orlofsky specifically ***didn't*** suggest there were any halachic authorities who said to create a separate day for the Holocaust.